# option in select is not selected without alert() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code snippet in my jquery. `update_obj['events']` holds the values of the options that I want to get selected. I have a set of `select` elements and their id begins with `event_drop_down_`. This code works fine. But if I comment the `alert(v)` the options are not get selected in the `select` elements. The only other event related to the `select` elements is `.change()`. I commented it and tried, still the issue persists. Any help/suggestion to overcome this is highly appreciated.

```
    var i =0;
$(update_obj['events']).each(function(v){
        alert(v);
    $('#event_drop_down_' + i + ' option[value=' + update_obj['events'][v] + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
    i = i+1;
});
```

Comment: Are the options added to the drop-down via asynchronous code, e.g., an Ajax request or something?

Comment: When (at what point if page's lifetime) are you running this script?

Comment: @nnnnnn it is from a $.post request

Comment: @Andrei there is a list of participants. when clicked on each a windows (jQuery dialog) appears with their details. There I have this set of `select` elements. Once the dialog is displayed, options are populated in `select` elements, this code is run

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(update_obj['events']).each(function(i,v){
    alert(i);
   $('#event_drop_down_' + i + ' option[value=' + update_obj['events'][i] + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
   i = i+1;
});
```

**OR**

```
$(update_obj['events']).each(function(i,v){
    alert(i);
   $('#event_drop_down_' + i + ' option[value=' + v + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
   i = i+1;
});
```

Comment: I tried, with `alert(i)' it works fine but without `alert(i)` it doesn't update the selected option.

Comment: why do you have `i=i+1` there i don't think you need that since you have `each` function.. can u show me what you get in updatedobj['events'].. ??

Comment: `i=i+1` is to iterate through the `select` elements. `each` is to iterate through the elements of `update_obj['events']`. Following is the output of `alert(update_obj['events'])`

    1,2

Comment: have you tried removing the `i=i+1` since i is the index of `update_obj['events']` in `each` loop... that should increase automatically...try it..

Comment: Thanks everyone. I figured and fixed the issue. I was receiving `options` through a `post` request. The error was that the time taken to receive the `post` response was too long that by that time the code to set the selected `options` have executed.

I changed the code so that only after the `options` are received the selected `option` setting code is executed.